# What's the role of Mediator and Proxy in Model View Controller pattern

Tags: model-view-controller

I understand the importance of Model, View and Controller. But further specialization of View into Mediator and Model into Proxy, confuses me. Is their any simple layman explanation exactly what Mediator and Proxy does, and why exactly they are separated from View and Model respectively ( Because in my opinion, View and Model are sufficent in themselves.. then why to make more classes)

Thanks
V.

Answer (score 0):

> The essence of the Mediator Pattern is to "Define an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact. Mediator promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction independently. "

The Mediator Pattern can be used between the Controller object and the Model objects. The Controller object provides an interface for View objects to alter the Model objects. These requests can be very complex altering a large number of collaborating Model objects. This collaboration behaviour may not be effectively stored in the Controller (Which should really delegate every behaviour request) or divided up nicely into the Model objects (e.g. a "Person" class having a "fileX93Form" method).

I can not understand why the Proxy pattern maybe relevant to MVC.

Comment: Perhaps a proxy in terms of fetching objects or data from a layered architecture?